# Google Chrome gives ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: google-chrome, homestead

I'm using Laravel in Homestead box. At first it worked without any problem, but recently I got this problem. Box is working perfectly fine, but when I try to reach my site (budget.app:8000) using Google Chrome, it gives ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, but it works on Firefox fine.

I followed all [these](https://aboutssl.org/fix-google-chrome-error-err_ssl_protocol_error/) steps and didn't work.

Homestead.yaml file

```
folders:

- map: ~/dev/web/php/laravel
  to: /home/vagrant/sites

- map: ~/dev/web/php/other
  to: /home/vagrant/other

sites:

- map: test.app
  to: /home/vagrant/sites/test/public/

- map: budget.app
  to: /home/vagrant/sites/budgetsystem-laravel/public
```

/etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   test.app
127.0.0.1   budget.app
```

I tried to brows this site using 2 computers (Win & Ubuntu) in same lan network, in both computers I got same the result (Chrome - ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, Firefox - works).

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess chrome forces HTTPS when you are using .app as of sometime in December. Included link below is a newsletter release from the beginning of December.

https://laravel-news.com/chrome-63-now-forces-dev-domains-https

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem.. I changed domains to " .test " and it worked. thank you so much.

Comment: No worries, I was having the same issue when I came across your post. :P