# Getting error ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when redirecting from Azure Active Directory to my website

Tags: c#, iis, azure-active-directory

Azure AD authentication was successful but on redirect chrome throwing error "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".
Below is my sign in code

```
 if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var claims = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().Claims.ToList();
        //Filter specific claim   
        if (claims != null && User.Identity.Name != null)
        {
```

}}

Comment: do you mean only when redirecting to your website, Chrome reports this error, if access your site directly, no error?

Comment: Yes, actually we are using Azure AD MFA authentication for our web site. From our web site we will be redirecting to Microsoft login to do authentication.   After successful authentication in Microsoft it will redirect to our web site.   Its working in firefox browser but in chrome its throwing error.

Comment: may i know whether you're website is hosted using https protocal? are you seeing this issue in production or when local debugging?

Comment: local its working. we are facing issue in production with load balancer. when the request going through load balancer we are having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with **Azure AD Authentication** to my knowledge. Make sure your website has **`SSL certificate`** installed. After installing that only, the redirect URL with **`https protocol`** works.

If the error continues even after installing that, the below are some of the reasons behind it:

1. The SSL has **expired** version of certificates.
2. When the date on your system is **not in sync** with the date of server that you are trying to access, this error may occur.
3. There may be a **firewall** which is blocking the website.
4. Sometimes the **QUIC protocol** present in Chrome stops the connection setup.
5. Check the **chrome extensions** which may also play a role in giving that error.

***To resolve that error, please go through below workarounds:***

- Adjust the date of your system to current date to sync with server.
- Disable the firewall that is blocking the website.
- Clear the browser cache and cookies that may have corrupted host files of website.
- Clear the SSL state in Chrome.
- Disable QUIC protocol of Chrome.
- Remove the chrome extensions that are generating error for website.
- **Update your chrome version.**

To know how to do these in detail, go through below references if they are helpful.

**References:**

[How to Fix the ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR (8 Easy Fixes) (hostingpill.com)](https://hostingpill.com/err_ssl_protocol_error/)

[homestead - Google Chrome gives ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035192/google-chrome-gives-err-ssl-protocol-error)

Comment: Thank you for your inputs.  Actually its working in chrome 88 version when i disable flag "Cookies without SameSite must be secure". But, its not working chrome 91+ version. As i  observed this flag is not available in current chrome version.

Comment: Hi @Sreedhar ! If you want to disable that flag in Chrome 91+ version, **add –disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies or –disable-features=CookieswithoutSameSitemustbesecure** in the Target field of the Google Chrome  properties and restart the browser. Refer to this  [link](https://piunikaweb.com/2021/06/14/google-chrome-flags-for-samesite-cookies-taken-away-after-update-v91/)